How to recover assets sent to ETH network but Safe was deployed on ZKsync network?
I accidentally sent assets to ETH address. Is there a way to deploy a ETH Safe with same address as my ZKsync Safe?

If you are talking about ZkSync Era (mainnet), sadly the answer is no.
Because of differences in how addresses are generated in ZkSync Era compared to EVM networks, the derivation method used by Safe will produce two different outputs. As of today these funds can be considered lost 
Best, Louis
